# How to get my chart elements to spread out? They are currently all stacked

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create g elements for my svg chart but they are all stacked on top of each other despite trying to set a transform distance on them.

Things I've tried: adding a transform translate distance for each one using "setAttribute". This did not seem to do anything.

```
        let tick = document.createElementNS(svg, "g");
        tick.setAttributeNS(svg, "transform", "translate("+ translateDistance +",0)");
        tick.setAttributeNS(svg, "class", "tick");

        let line = document.createElementNS(svg, "line");
        line.setAttributeNS(svg, "class", "y-axis-zero-line axis-line dash gray");
        line.setAttributeNS(svg, "x1", "-13");
        line.setAttributeNS(svg, "y1", "0");
        line.setAttributeNS(svg, "x2", "-13");
        line.setAttributeNS(svg, "y2", "240");
        tick.appendChild(line);

        let textDay = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "class", "label-day");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "dy", "0.71em");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "y", "-28");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "x", "0");
        let textDayNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][0]);
        textDay.appendChild(textDayNode);
        tick.appendChild(textDay);

        let textTime = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "class", "label-time");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "dy", "0.71em");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "y", "-15");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(svg, "x", "0");
        let textTimeNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][1]);
        textTime.appendChild(textTimeNode);
        tick.appendChild(textTime);

        totalXAxis.appendChild(tick);
```

Here is an editable example: https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/RwwQOPY

Expected result is the ticks are spaced out across the top of the chart. 
Actual result is the ticks are all stacked near the origin of the chart as if the transform isn't doing anything.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change line

```
tick.setAttributeNS(svg, "transform", "translate("+ translateDistance +",0)");
```

to

```
tick.style.transform = "translate("+translateDistance+"px)";
```

Note: You will notice bug with your distance calculation, but at least things are translating.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Answer (score 0):

You use the namespace (`const svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";`) only when you create a new element:

`let tick = document.createElementNS(svg, "g");`

When you set the attribute you don't use the namespace. You use `null` instead:

`tick.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate("+ translateDistance +",0)");`

```js
const labels = [
  ['Mon', '7 AM'],
  ['Tue', '7 AM'],
  ['Tue', '8 AM'],
  ['Tue', '9 AM'],
  ['Tue', '10 AM'],
  ['Tue', '11 AM'],
  ['Tue', '12 PM']
]

const xAxis = document.getElementById('total-x-ticks');

function createTotalLabels(labels, totalChartWidth, totalXAxis) {
  const hoursInterval = 1;
  const svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

  let spacing = totalChartWidth / labels.length;
  let currentDay = '';
  
  const formattedLabels = labels.map((label, i) => {
    if (i % hoursInterval === 0) {
      if (label[0] !== currentDay) {
        currentDay = label[0];
        return [label[0], label[1]];
      }
      return ['', label[1]];
    }
    return ['', ''];
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < formattedLabels.length; i++) {
    let translateDistance;
    if (i === 0) {
      translateDistance = 15;
    } else {
      translateDistance = i * spacing + 15;
    }
    if (formattedLabels[i][1].length && i !== 0) {
      if (formattedLabels[i][0].length) {
        let tick = document.createElementNS(svg, "g");
        tick.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate("+ translateDistance +",0)");
        tick.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "tick");

        let line = document.createElementNS(svg, "line");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "y-axis-zero-line axis-line dash gray");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", "-13");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", "0");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", "-13");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", "240");
        tick.appendChild(line);

        let textDay = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "label-day");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", "0.71em");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "-28");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
        let textDayNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][0]);
        textDay.appendChild(textDayNode);
        tick.appendChild(textDay);

        let textTime = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "label-time");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", "0.71em");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "-15");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
        let textTimeNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][1]);
        textTime.appendChild(textTimeNode);
        tick.appendChild(textTime);

        totalXAxis.appendChild(tick);
      } else {
        let tick = document.createElementNS(svg, "g");
        tick.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate("+ translateDistance +",0)");
        tick.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "tick");

        let line = document.createElementNS(svg, "line");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "y-axis-zero-line axis-line dash gray");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", "-13");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", "0");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", "-13");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", "240");
        tick.appendChild(line);

        let textDay = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "label-day");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", "0.71em");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "-28");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
        let textDayNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][0]);
        textDay.appendChild(textDayNode);
        tick.appendChild(textDay);

        let textTime = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "label-time gray");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", "0.71em");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "-15");
        textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
        let textTimeNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][1]);
        textTime.appendChild(textTimeNode);
        tick.appendChild(textTime);

        totalXAxis.appendChild(tick);
      }
    } else {
      let tick = document.createElementNS(svg, "g");
      tick.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate("+ translateDistance +",0)");
      tick.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "tick");

      let textDay = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "label-day");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", "0.71em");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "-28");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
      let textDayNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][0]);
      textDay.appendChild(textDayNode);
      tick.appendChild(textDay);

      let textTime = document.createElementNS(svg, "text");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "label-time");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", "0.71em");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "-15");
      textDay.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
      let textTimeNode = document.createTextNode(formattedLabels[i][1]);
      textTime.appendChild(textTimeNode);
      tick.appendChild(textTime);

      totalXAxis.appendChild(tick);
    }
  }
}

createTotalLabels(labels, 500, xAxis);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}

svg .bar {
  fill: #4a93ff;
}
svg .axis {
  font: 11px 'Solis';
}
svg .axis path,
svg .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
svg .x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
svg .axis-line {
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
svg .axis-line.dash.gray {
  stroke-dasharray: 4;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
svg .tick {
  opacity: 1;
}
svg .tick text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
svg .tick line.gray,
svg line.gray {
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
svg .label-day,
svg .y-tick {
  font-weight: bold;
}
svg .label-time {
  font-weight: normal;
}
svg .label-time.gray {
  fill: #878787;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="total-chart" height="285" width="100%">
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="total-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(76, 150, 254, 1.00)" />
     <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="rgba(76, 150, 254, 0.50)" />
     <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(209, 225, 250, 0.1)" />
    </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <g transform="translate(32,40)">
    <g class="y axis" id="total-y-ticks">
     <line
      class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line"
      id="y-axis-zero-line-total"
      x1="0"
      y1="0"
      x2="0"
      y2="240"
     />
    </g>
    <g>
     <polygon id="total-chart-polygon" fill="url('#total-gradient')" />
    </g>
    <g class="x axis"
     id="total-x-ticks"
     transform="translate(0,0)"
    >
     <line
      class="x-axis-zero-line axis-line"
      id="x-axis-zero-line-total"
      x1="0"
      y1="240"
      x2="600"
      y2="240"
     />
    </g>
   </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```